# drawing a circular arc using arcpy

Tags: arcgis, arcpy

I would like to draw a circular arc between two angles and of certain radius using arcpy.Just to clarify it is not the blade but rather only the arc part.
I have thousands of such points so need some script to automate the process.
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "draw." Draw where? Do you have a graphical map available you're trying to draw in, or are you just trying to save a shape?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an arc between two points using the great circle method.  Use [XY To Line (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000tv000000) to accomplish this.

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set local variables
input_table = r"c:\workspace\city2city.dbf"
out_lines = r"c:\workspace\flt4421.gdb\routing001"

#XY To Line
arcpy.XYToLine_management(input_table,out_lines,
                         "LOND1","LATD1","LOND2",
                         "LATD2","GREAT_CIRCLE","idnum")
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for your reply. But the problem with this api is that  i need to have two endpoints for this, where as i just have the center  point of the circle, radius and the two angles between which i need to draw the arc. Please suggest some other alternatives.

Comment: @ArijitBose It wouldn't be too hard to calculate the end points given the info you have.